# Insert multiple rows in fusion table from 1 data entry operation in google forms

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I already connected a google form to a fusion table as per those instructions
https://kh-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/code/instructions.html

When the user fills up the form a new row in the fusion table is inserted.

However, I am presenting the user with one question with checkbox - If multiple checkboxes are selected, for each option, i want to insert a separate row.

Example:

- Name ( text )
- Field of interest (check box):  IT, Art, History, etc

in the fusion table, i am getting

- my name -  IT, History

I want to get:

- my name - IT
- my name - History

It is mostly due to the needs to represent stuff in a network.

i really really really appreciate the feedback/help

Best,

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by modifying the script you are using. If you look at the `onFormSubmit` function, this is what creates one row from the submitted data. You could modify the script to generate multiple rows, according to how many comma-separated items are in your lists.

A quick example mockup: (I have assumed a column name of 'interest')

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  ...
  // The values entered into the form, mapped by question.
  var interests = e.nameValues['interest'].split(',');
  for (i in interests)
  {
    var formValues = e.namedValues;
    formValues['interest'] = interests[i];

    // Insert the data into the Fusion Table.
    var rowId = createRecord(formValues);
    if (!rowId) {
      rowId = -1;
    }
    insertRowId(rowId, row);
  }
}
```